# How do I mock non-global node variables _filename or __dirname in jest?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, jestjs

`__filename` and `__dirname` are the absolute file paths in which a code is entered. Per Node.js documentation (and confirmed) these 2 special global variables are injected rather than being part of the  the `global` object so cannot be configured via `globalThis`/`global` within jest.

Example function: `utils.ts`

```js
export const getFileAndDirName = () => ({
 relevantFile: __filename.split('/')?.[3],
 rootPath: __dirname,
})
```

Example test code which does not work: `utils.test.ts`

```js
it('finds the file path where the function was executed', () => {
  globalThis.__filename = '/Users/me/work/utils/index.ts'
  expect(getFileAndDirName()).toEqual('utils')
  globalThis.__filename = '/Users/me/work/tests/index.ts'
  expect(getFileAndDirName()).toEqual('tests')
})
```

**Alternatives/Work arounds:**

I'm aware that I can refactor my code to still be able to test this:

```js
export const safelyExtractThirdElement = (filePath = '') => filePath.split('/')?.[3]

export const getFileAndDirName = () => ({
 relevantFile: safelyExtractThirdElement(__filename),
 rootPath: __dirname,
})
```

This solution enables me to avoid mocking `__filename`... however ideally I wouldn't need to change my actual code and keep private internal utilities un-tested, and also this is a bit of a simplified arbitrary example compared to my own.

I can also hack my code for this to work, but I feel that testing should make code stronger not hackier:

```js
__filename = globalThis.__filename || __filename // will probably work since globalThis.__filename is never defined.
```

### With this strategy I can mock __filename and allow my code to read it but this is again hacking implementation.

Is there some ideal/not-so ideal strategy for mocking these special variables in jest?

The real question is if it is possible to mock `__dirname` or `__filename` or should I accept that these may not be mocked for node jest and circumvent that limitation?

**Background: __filename, __dirname**

The fact that this doesn't work does not surprise me: if we look at the Node.js documentation for `__filename` it indicates plainly that __filename and __dirname you may assume are globals but are NOT.

```
__dirname#

This variable may appear to be global but is not. See __dirname.

__filename#

This variable may appear to be global but is not. See __filename.
```

https://nodejs.org/api/globals.html#__dirname

```
(function(exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) {
// Module code actually lives in here
});
```

The question is if it is possible, how would one mock __filename or __dirname with jest. Jest documentation makes it pretty clear how to mock and temporarily set functions using globalThis, but what about these non-global globals?

Comment: Did you ever find any info about this?

Comment: I wasn't able to do it... maybe it would be a "better practice" to use a "updateFileName" and "getFileName" so that you can mock those... but I still don't love it.